# Simultanusely access multiple 3D array with different indexes for each 3D array

Tags: numpy, array-broadcasting

I have 8000 3D arrays stacked in a 4D array with dimensions 8000x16x8x8:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((8000,16,8,8))
```

now I have 3 arrays (size of 8000) of indices to access in each axis:

```
arr_x = np.random.randint(size=8000, high=16 , low=0)
arr_y = np.random.randint(size=8000, high=8 , low=0)
arr_z = np.random.randint(size=8000, high=8 , low=0)
```

I want to access simultaneously for every 3D array located in index i (where i goes between 0 to 7999) the specific cell in index arr(i,arr_x[i], arr_y[i],arr_z[i])

A naive for loop implementation, with a simple print will look like:

```
for i in range(0,8000):
    print(arr[i,arr_x[i], arr_y[i], arr_z[i]])
```

sure I tried arr[:, arr_x, arr_y, arr_z], but it fetches 8000 times **every** 3D array.

Comment: Simply `arr[np.arange(len(arr)), arr_x, arr_y, arr_z]`. Info - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

Comment: haha :) thanks so much!